# Why index REBUILD does not reduce index fragmentation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I used `ALTER INDEX REBUILD` to remove index fragmentation. In some cases, `REBUILD` does not seem to remove this fragmentation. What are the reasons why `REBUILD` does not remove fragmentation?

Comment: What is the size of the table? What are the fragmentation stats? If it is a small table the fact the first few pages are in mixed extents and leaf pages and upper levels of the index are intermingled could well explain it

Comment: The table size is 80 kb and fragmentation is 50%.

Comment: that is only 10 pages. You shouldn't worry about fragmentation in tables so small. Likely it is due to most of the pages being in mixed extents